# Logstash grok filter with if statements

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am having trouble using if statements along with a grok filter in order to filter my log data.

Example of my code:

**.conf FILE**

```
input {
    stdin { }
}

filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]

        match => {"message" => "%{API_CALL}"}
    }
    if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
        grok {
            add_tag => ["External API call"]
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

**custom patterns**

```
API_CALL called
```

If I run this configuration and give an input string of `called` then I will get a `grokparsefailure`. But if I get rid of the if statement block and run it again, I will have a successful match.

All help is appreciated.